# How to get list of all wcf services running on a machine?

Tags: wcf

How can I to get list of all wcf services running on a machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot - you need to know the services and their endpoints. There's no API to give you all running services on a given machine from the outside.

Marc

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a very old question, but just in case someone comes across this and needs an answer, you can get a list of services on a machine using the PerformanceCounterCategory class and getting all of the instances.

```
var category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("ServiceModelService 3.0.0.0", "machine name");
var instances  = category.GetInstanceNames();

foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance);
}
```

Comment: Jason! Where and how did you come up with this? :)

Comment: Note that later versions of .NET require different version specifiers: for example, with .NET 4.5 you need to replace 3.0.0.0 with 4.0.0.0. (I suspect the original answer was for .NET 3.0 or .NET 3.5). To see what categories are available on your machine use `var categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();` then search through the list for "ServiceModelService".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a way to do that. They're not centrally managed.